# Selenium:: Trigger hotkey to external windows application from selenium?

Tags: selenium, protractor

I have a screen recorder application called bandicam that is triggered when I press a certain hotkey. However, if I sendKeys() in selenium, it does not seem to trigger the recording app. Is there a way to make this possible?

I have tried changing the hotkey in my recording app and selenium to F9, ctrl + "i", and ctrl + shift + "i". But it never triggered the recording.

**environment**
Typescript
Protractor
chrome

**code sample**
`browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, 'i')).perform();`

Answer (score 1):

Bandicam is a desktop application.  The sendKeys function wouldn't trigger anything outside of the browser environment.

You can think of sendKeys as faking out a keyboard press in the browser listeners level. So a keyboard press never actually happens for the computer, operating system or other programs.